# How to monitor messages rate in Kafka topics?

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring, anomaly-detection

How can I get alerted when there is a message rate in some topic higher or lower than usual?

Comment: I've edited your question because asking for tools is considered off-topic. [help] But basically, you need to enable JMX on the brokers and (Java) clients, then you need a tool to export JMX values into a aggregate system, such as Prometheus, as mentioned, but there are still other options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kafka emits tons of metrics that allow to monitor its usage and health. This includes metrics for incoming message rate, see the [Monitoring](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#monitoring) section in the docs.

Your use case is typically achieved with a tool that handles metrics and is able to fire alerts based on user defined queries.

For example, [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) handles that very well. You need to set it up so metrics from Kafka are forwarded to Prometheus (using https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter). As it's a very common use case, you'll find hundreds of articles online that describe how to set that up. The JMX exporter has [sample configs](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/tree/master/example_configs) for the Kafka JMX patterns, as well.

Once the metrics are in Prometheus you can aggregate them across brokers and set up [Alerts](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/overview/).